# Trying to Install on 2016 HP Pavilion but getting a black screen

Tags: hp

total Linux n00b here. I have a HP Pavilion from 2016 I'm trying to install Ubuntu on.

I've downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 and made a bootable ISO on a usb drive using Rufus. I restart, hit ESC and boot from the USB drive. It brings up a menu where I can select Ubuntu, Ubuntu (safe graphics...) and two other options I'm forgetting. When I hit Ubuntu, the screen is just black, it's on, but there's nothing on there.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, perhaps this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264087/blank-screen-after-installing-amd-drivers-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Here's my solution.

I first disabled Secure Boot in the Bios. That didn't work for me so I looked for other things to tweak in the BIOS. I found Delete All Secure Boot Keys. I did that, and when I tried booting from the USB it worked!